# fastqCleaner failing to launch in RStudio

Tags: r, bioconductor, fastq, fastqc, rstudio

When I execute:

`> FastqCleaner:::launch_fqc()()`

I get the following output

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4863
Warning: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
Warning: Error in : Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
  85: stop
  84: FUN
  83: lapply
  82: buildTabset
  81: tabsetPanel_
  80: func
  78: tabsetPanel
Warning: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
Warning: Error in : Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
  85: stop
  84: FUN
  83: lapply
  82: buildTabset
  81: tabsetPanel_
  80: func
  78: tabsetPanel
```

Have I done something wrong or is the function broken in some way?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the navbar page, downgrading shiny to 1.6 or in my case 1.4 fixed it for me, the detailed link to find to the solution is here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3556

Cheers.